# How do I disregard the time portion when comparing two date values?

Tags: c#, winforms, date, comparison, datetimepicker

I want this to equate to false when the date displayed is today's date:

`if (dateTimePickerScheduleDate.Value < DateTime.Now)`

...but it doesn't, because the DTP's value contains "midnight" whereas "Now" is after midnight.

How do I "trunc" these values so that it disregards the time portion?

Comment: Got it: if (dateTimePickerScheduleDate.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)

Comment: Change it to an answer and accept it - ok to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(dateTimePickerScheduleDate.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
{
}
```

The Date property returns a `DateTime` reflecting only the Date component of your `DateTime` object with its time component zero'ed out.

Comment: You may also use .CompareTo(Datetime obj) instead of <

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: How does converting one of the dates to string help?